# javascript select option in different select box based on previous selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have 2 select elements

`producttype` and `voip_type`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#producttype").hide();
});
$('#voip_type').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="no"){
        $("#producttype").show()
    }
    if( $(this).val()==="storage"){

    }
    else
    {
        $("#producttype").hide()
    }
});
</script>
```

I want to show `producttype` if `voip_type === 'no'` (This works)

I want to select a certain option on `producttype` if `voip_type === 'storage'`

Else just to show `producttype` and select a certain option

im not sure what to put in the javascript for `if( $(this).val()==="storage"){`

here is a fiddle with the HTML too: http://jsfiddle.net/nBDfX/

Comment: Like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/nBDfX/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#producttype").hide();
});
$('#voip_type').on('change',function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if( val ==="no"){
        $("#producttype").show()
    }
    else if( val ==="extension")
    {
        $("#producttype").val("Offsite Backup").show()
    }
    else {
        $("#producttype").val("PC Maintenance").show()
    }
});
```

[JsFiddle - Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/PpX5p/)

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure about youre asking, but if you want to select any option on $('#producttype') just do this:

```
$('#producttype').val('Broadband');
```